# Not found for ModelAndView based mapping in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to apply thymeleaf template engine in Spring Boot application. Template exists in: **src/main/resources/templates/user/new.html**

```
@GetMapping("/new")
public ModelAndView newUser() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/new");
    return mav;
}
```

When I test with String response, it works well, no problem with the route.

Here're my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Than I decided to add starter as told in the tutorials:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But than, when I run application I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]: Error creating bean with name 'thymeleafViewResolver' defined in class path resource
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. When I only added starter dependency, it all worked well. Than I added layout-dialect and layout also worked like a charm.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```